# tkinter label - se lanzan los dos eventos, click y doble click a la vez

Tags: tkinter, eventos

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, font

class   Intento1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        labeltop = tk.Label(master, text= "Etiqueta superior", background = "red")
        labeltop.grid(row=0, column=0)

        labeltop.bind("<Button-1>", self.callLabelTop)
        labeltop.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.callLabelTopDouble)

        self.quitButton = tk.Button(master, text="quit", command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def callLabelTop(self, event):
        print("Intento1: Single click in TopLabel")

    def callLabelTopDouble(self, event):
        print("Intento1: Double click in TopLabel")


if __name__ == "__main__": 

    print(sys.version)
    root = tk.Tk()

    app = Intento1(root)
    root.progID = sys.argv[0] + " --> "                  # recoge nombre del programa
    root.title(root.progID + 'Sample application')
    root.mainloop()
```

Cuando hago double click en la etiqueta, se me lanzan, a la vez, los eventos de single click y doble click.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal o que omito?
¿Es el comportamiento standard?

El interface de stackoverflow me pide que añada mas detalles, para dejarme publicar. Creo que con lo descrito es suficiente, ¿no?

Comment: No estas omitiendo nada,te comparto esta informacion que encontre por ahi:<Double-Button-1>
Button 1 was double clicked. You can use Double or Triple as prefixes. Note that if you bind to both a single click (<Button-1>) and a double click, both bindings will be called. Basicamente lo que dice es que si hay 2 binds asociados a un widget,uno de un solo click y otro de 2 clicks, se ejecutaran ambos

Comment: ¿Alguna pista o ejemplo de como tratar esta situación, y evitar el proceso del single click? Porque este problema / situación tiene que ser muy frecuente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya comentaba @Franco, es el comportamiento esperado. No obstante podemos hacer algo, implementar nuestro propio método para manejar el evento.

Realmente un doble click no es más que dos click seguidos en un intervalo de tiempo corto, cada vez que tengamos un click podemos comprobar si se produce otro en `t` milisegundos, si no se produce tenemos un click simple, si se produce uno doble. Para ello podemos hacer uso de `after`:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, font


class Intento1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self._last_click_event = None

        labeltop = tk.Label(master, text="Etiqueta superior", background="red")
        labeltop.grid(row=0, column=0)

        labeltop.bind("<Button-1>", self._on_click_handler)

        self.quit_button = tk.Button(master, text="quit", command=self.quit)
        self.quit_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def _on_click_handler(self, event):
        if event is None and self._last_click_event is not None:
            self._last_click_event = None
            self.call_label_top(self._last_click_event)
        elif self._last_click_event is None and event is not None:
            self._last_click_event = event
            self.after(300, self._on_click_handler, None)
        elif event is not None:
            self.call_label_top_double(event)
            self._last_click_event = None

    def call_label_top(self, event):
        print("Intento1: Single click in TopLabel")

    def call_label_top_double(self, event):
        print("Intento1: Double click in TopLabel")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.version)
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Intento1(root)
    root.progID = sys.argv[0] + " --> "  # recoge nombre del programa
    root.title(root.progID + 'Sample application')
    root.mainloop()
```

En este caso el tiempo es de 300 ms, podemos ajustarlo si lo deseamos. Obviamente esto hace que un evento click simple se retrase 300 ms en mostrarse, pero esto es imposible d evitar si no queremos lanzar ambos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]